# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8083/xyx/mex'

Tags: wcf

I am trying to add an Enum member to an already existing DataContract. When I try to update the service reference I get an error "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8083/xyx/mex'".

How to find the problems associated with this issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: Is the WCF service up and running on the specified port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your mex endpoint with `..\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe`

Comment: Yes service is running :)... Will try WCFTestClient

Comment: check your path in service reference `Configure Service Reference` in visual studio and check your `app.config` in project with service references

Comment: @burning_legion... thanks wcftestclient was useful... Used IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults and found the issue.... Many Thanks